# Pillars of Eternity: Better to buy from Mac App Store or from Steam?

Tags: mac-appstore, games, game-center, steam

I haven't played a video game on my computer in over a decade and I'm unfamiliar with modern technologies. If I want to buy Pillars of Eternity, am I better off getting it through the mac app store or through Steam?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Steam. With steam, you'll be able to play it on Windows too, should you ever have the need. The same can't be said for the MAS, which only offers the Mac version. It's a nice bit of future-proofing, incase you ever get a Windows PC in the future. To put it simply, you get more for your money.

Answer (score -2):

Go with Steam.

- Play on Windows if you want to.
- Faster update.